# Meteor Change the sender info on reset password email

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

When you leave the accounts-password email template as is it shows the sender of the reset password email as Meteor Accounts.

When I try to change it like this

```
Accounts.emailTemplates.from = "Myself <me@myself.com>";
```

then the email never gets sent. Does anyone know what the correct way to change this is?

Comment: I've tried many different values for the from address, even exactly as it appears when I receive an email from that address, and nothing works. Perhaps this is more of an issue with my SMTP server than it is with Meteor.

Answer (score 4):

I've just tried to reproduce and think I know what the problem is.. first off I put that line in my client startup (didn't work) but as soon as I moved it to the server startup function the emails were being sent from the correct name/address.

See if that works for you.

David

Comment: I have this running from server->startup. Also see my comment below to tarmes

Answer (score 0):

Does your SMTP provider allow you to send email from that address?

If you're running from meteor.com using they're default SMPT service then I doubt they'll let you set the from address to anything you like for security reasons.

Comment: Yes, I do have the address that I am using setup for SMTP and it does work.. I can change `siteName, resetPassword.subject` and `resetPassword.text` just fine but setting `from` breaks it.

Comment: Sure, but changing the from address changes everything. Which SMTP server are you using?